# get primary key of recently added record and insert into another table as foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Am using asp.net as front end and MySQL as back end.
I have two tables "Registration" and "User".
I have a registration form, in that i have registration details along with login details.
Wen user click register the registration details is saved to "Registration" and login details is saved to "User" with foreign key Reg_Id of table Registration.

this is my code:

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.Parse(txtDob.Text);
string formattedDate = dob.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

string qry = "insert into Registration(First_Name,Last_Name,Dob,Place,Zip,Phone_Number)values(@fname,@lname,@dob,@place,@zip,@phone);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, Connection.get());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFname.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLname.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", formattedDate);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place", txtPlace.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", txtZip.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

int modified = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 

Connection.close();

string qryToUser = "insert into User(User_Name,Password)values(@user,@password)";

MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(qryToUser, Connection.get());

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPasswordConfirm.Text);

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am not able to get the REG_Id using cmd.ExecuteScalar() method.
Is there any other way or did i do anything wrong???
Please someone help me

Comment: Please format your code snippets appropriately and remove phrases like "Please someone help me" from your question - We are here to help you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use LastInsertedId field :

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long modified = cmd.LastInsertedId;
```

Comment: Good, Thank you too!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have executed `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` before calling `ExecuteScalar()` method. I guess that the second call might fail and therefore not return an id.

Maybe you should check out a tutorial on [how to use MySQL with C#](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/)